# Moving Data from an old table to a new one with same column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I am setting up my schools database and i have been told that they have 2 database tables, with the same columns. they need me to move the data from the old table over to the new table, but no duplicates should be present, also, the id of one record in the old table could mean something, and the same id in the new table could mean something else, i wouldnt want the old id to have a new item attached to it. also this system is never on hold so its constantly having new data captured... how can i get to doing this?

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables, sample data as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table), both duplicates and original rows, and desired final state.

Comment: So you're not really 'setting it up' then

Comment: *this system is never on hold so its constantly having new data captured...* Does this means that new data is inserted into the table which must be emptified?

Comment: It's not clear how you identify duplicates or what you want do do with them if detected.

Comment: if a dupe is detected, it needs to be removed, so say someone had an id number inthe old db and the same person is in a new db with the same id number then one record needs to go

Comment: 'one record needs to go' - which one?